# GTM does not reset dataLayer on page navigation

Tags: next.js, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I am trying to integrate GTM into my single page NextJS app. I inject my script into the _document.js as suggested:

```
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];`
            }} />
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
              new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
              j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
          '    https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
              })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','${getGtmTrackingId()}');`,
        }} />
        </Head>
        <body>
            <noscript
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=${getGtmTrackingId()}" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>`,
            }}
        />
        <Main />
        </body>
    </Html>
```

My question is this: every time i navigate through pages, I see that dataLayer still contains the events that were fired on previous pages. Do I need to reset my dataLayer on every url change? Do I reach the limits of GTM if I do not reset my dataLayer on url change or is it okay to include all events that fired?

I tried resetting the dataLayer like this, but if I do that gtm stops sending events.

In my _app.js file:

```
useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart',() => {window.dataLayer = []});
}, [router.events]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this? We have the same problem with Nuxt.js application that dataLayer variable keeps growing on each page view.

Comment: @Eljas no we did not find a solution, we left it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

try this on before you push a page view event:

```
window.dataLayer.push(() => {
  window.google_tag_manager["your_container_id"].dataLayer.reset()
})
```