# How to remove datalayer from history event with react-gtm-module

Tags: react-gtm-module

When I add a custom datalayer as described [here](https://bestofreactjs.com/repo/alinemorelli-react-gtm-react-tag-input#:%7E:text=Multiple%20dataLayer%20example) it will fire a message that can be seen in the G-Tagmanager with the added datalayer, but it will also show in every rout-/ history change event after that.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const tryToSendGADataLayer = () => {
    const tagManagerArgs = {
      dataLayer: {
        ecommerce: {
          purchase: {
            actionField: {..},
            products: [{..}]
          }
        }
      },
      dataLayerName: 'ecommerce'
    }
    TagManager.dataLayer(tagManagerArgs)

}
```

I only want the datalayer to be added in the Message event and not in all the events after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.google_tag_manager[ GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID].dataLayer.reset()
```

[GTM does not reset dataLayer on page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66172573/gtm-does-not-reset-datalayer-on-page-navigation)